# Erro ao instalar cordova Windows 8.1

Tags: node.js, apache-cordova, windows, instalador

estou com problemas para instalar o cordova na minha maquina, segui os passos do link [própio Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/cli/#link-1) porem ele nao estava funcionando, está dando erro como segue abaixo :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu passei por isso, a solução que funcionou para mim foi baixar uma versão específica do nodejs (node-v0.10.32-x64) ou (node-v0.10.32-x86)!